# How to get the help sign after input with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to get the help sign after the input text, although I can only managed to get it in the next "line"

Here is the code I have:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-content="Help goes here"><strong>?</strong></a>
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the bootply: http://www.bootply.com/121600

Comment: you mean inside of the textbox ?

Comment: @bboymaanu no, after the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to wrap the input and it's text link a `list-inline`..

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email"></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-content="Help goes here"><strong>?</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/121629